# bash while loop irritate with single quote

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I have a few lines code.
I just want to check if argument `$1` is in the file with a `while` loop so I write this code.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -z $1 ]
then
    update=$1;
    while read line
    do
        if [ $update == $line ]
        then
            echo "yes";
        fi
    done<./available_updates
fi
```

But in debugging if I run

```
[root@pc bagheri]# bash -x ./test.sh my_value
```

it says:

```
+ '[' my_value == 'my_value' ']'
```

and jump over that condition just because of these two single quotes and not printing the 'yes' word, but I am 100% sure that the `my_value` is existed in `available_updates` file. What should I do for that?

Comment: Try quoting all your variables, for instance `"$update" == "$line"`, because if you don't `$line` can expand into multiple strings instead of one.

Comment: What version of bash are you running? I can't reproduce what you're seeing with version 3.2, 4.0, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 5.0

Comment: Is "my_value" the actual value involved? In not, what is the actual value?

Comment: @Mahdi, if `$update` and `$line` contain only `my_value`, the `set -x` output from the shell will _not_ quote it. Above, you say that the output has no quotes around the first `my_value` but there are quotes around the second. Is that right? Are you sure that's the exact output? Because the presence of quotes there indicates the value has some special characters, other than letters and the underscore, but your output doesn't show them. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @glenn-jackman GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Gordon Davisson, the actual value is roundcube

Comment: Reduce the file `available_updates` to just one line which triggers the problem and add the output of `od -t c -t x1 available_updates` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use shell loops to process text](/q/321697)

```
#! /bin/sh -
update="${1?missing update argument}"
grep -Fxqe "$update" < available_updates && echo yes
```

Some of the problems in your code:

- parameter expansions must be quoted in Bourne-like shells.
- the syntax to read a line with `read` is `IFS= read -r line`, not `read line`.
- The syntax to check that a script is given at least one argument if `[ "$#" -gt 0 ]` (though see also the `${1?error message}` approach). `[ ! -z "$1" ]` (here adding the missing quotes) only check whether the first one is non-empty.

The `'` you see in the `xtrace` output are not part of the data passed to the `[` command, they are output there to make sure what's displayed constitutes valid shell code. That suggests `$line` doesn't contain just `my_value` there, but possibly some other invisible character as well which `bash` thinks need quoted. It could possibly be something like a U+FEFF, the "byte-order-mark" character.

Running `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < available-updates` could help reveal those invisible characters.

Comment: Additionally, the double "==" comparison is bashism, POSIX sh expects single "=".

Comment: @TomaszPala, true `==` is not POSIX. Rather a kshism, but here the she-bang has `#!/bin/bash` so we're outside POSIX realm.

Comment: OP calls bash, but this answer refers to sh - I'm just going to bring out that, apart from being absolutely not suitable for any kind of text processing, bash nor it's syntax is not standard way to write portable scripts (especially when they are being "ported" by changing she-bang line only).